# Error with return statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code which is not working.

```
function myfun()
   {
       return
       {
       alert("para"); 
       } 
   };

   myfun();
```

I have read about the javascript's automatic semicolon insertion. I corrected the above code as

```
return{
       alert("para"); 
       }
```

But still got the error : `unexpected token (`.
I wonder why?

NOTE: I don't need the solution but I need the explanation why the above code in not working.

**EDIT**

According to the book, javascript the good parts, the return statement if returns value must be in same line as return expression.

ie

```
 return {
status: true
};
```

AND

```
 return
{
status: true
};
```

Is wrong.Then How come

```
function myfun(para)
   {
     var status; 

       return
       {
          status : alert(para)
       };
   };


  myfun("ok");
```

produce no error.It won't work but shows no error as well.It works when the `{` is in the same line as return.

ie

```
 function myfun(para)
   {
     var status; 

       return{
          status : alert(para)
       };
   };

   myfun("ok");
```

Comment: What are the braces `{}`  around `alert` supposed to do?

Comment: Nothing, the `return alert("para")` works perfectly fine. I just want to know why the above one doesn't work.

Comment: Actually returning an alert is the same as returning `undefined`, except the alert will be shown though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
return {
   alert("para"); 
}
```

the `{...}` are interpreted as [**object literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). An object literal has the form

```
{
    key: value,
    //...
}
```

Object literals cannot contain arbitrary statements.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've difficulties with [ASI](https://es5.github.io/#x7.9) and the difference between run-time and parsing-time.

Where as

```
return {
    status: true
};
```

is a correct way to return an object, ASI will take an action in the following code:

```
return
{ //  ^-- ASI will insert a semicolon here
    status: true
};
```

The semicolon is automatically inserted, and at *run-time* all lines after `return` are ignored. However, *at parsing time*, everything counts, and if there's a syntax error, like in your first example, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Ohh. That ASI can lead to surprising behaviour for people who think whitespace is insignificant. Nasty...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that error is because JS is expecting a value to the key "para".

There is no compulsion to return in a JavaScript function. If your intention is to test if the control goes to the function, you can simply change it to

```
function myfun() { alert("para"); }
```

if you want to return an object with string "para" you should change it to

```
function myfun() { return { "text": "para" }; }
```